# Any series which increases extremely slowly and whose lower bound is $\log^{\circ k}(n+1)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms, divergent-series

The sum of the reciprocals of all positive integers is bounded below by $\log(n+1)$; that is,
$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-1}<\log(n+1).$$

The sum of the reciprocals of all prime numbers is bounded below by $\log\left(\log(n+1)\right)$; that is,
$$\displaystyle\sum_{p\text{ is a prime with }p\leq n}p^{-1}<\log\left(\log(n+1)\right).$$

So is there a series that increases even slower and is bounded below by $\log\left(\log\left(\log(n+1)\right)\right)$? How about the lower bound $\log^{\circ k}(n+1)$ ( that is, $\log x$ composite with itself $k-1$ times)?

Ideally, given a positive integer $k\geq 2$, I was hoping to find a series $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ such that
$$\log^{\circ k}(n+1)<\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k<\log^{\circ (k-1)}(n+1).$$

Answer (score 1):

Given $\{b_n\}$ a sequence converging to $+\infty$, you can always find a series whose partial sums grow like $b_n$. It is enough to take $a_n=b_{n+1}-b_n$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is a series whose partial sums are 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^na_k=b_{n+1}-b_1.
$$

Comment: Thank you! Your answer satisfies all the conditions that I have described in my question. Actually I was hoping to find something that is more like the example of the sum of reciprocal of all primes or the sum of the reciprocal of all natural numbers, etc.